# How do I make this program check if an input is an integer without causing an error in runtime and stop the loop with a sentinel value?

Tags: java, loops, integer, runtime-error

I've been trying to root out a runtime error from my program caused while it is checking if user input is an integer, and if it isn't one to print out an error message, and ask for another input that is an integer. I've also noticed that with checking the integer now my program keeps asking for more input instead of stopping the loop if a user inputs a negative integer. Here's the part of my program code that is having issues:

```
do
    {
        System.out.println("Enter an integer grade percentage: ");
        examScore = keyboard.nextInt();
        if (examScore != (int)examScore) {
            System.out.println("Not an integer, please try again.");            
                
            if (examScore >= 90 && examScore <=100) {
                gradeA++;
                totalScores++;
            }
            else if (examScore >= 80 && examScore <=89) {
                gradeB++;
                totalScores++;
            }
            else if (examScore >= 70 && examScore <=79) {
                gradeC++;
                totalScores++;
            }
            else if (examScore >= 60 && examScore <=69) {
                gradeD++;
                totalScores++;
            }
            else if (examScore >=0 && examScore <= 59)
                gradeF++;
                totalScores++; 
            }
        else {
            if (examScore >= 90 && examScore <=100) {
                gradeA++;
                totalScores++;
            }
            else if (examScore >= 80 && examScore <=89) {
                gradeB++;
                totalScores++;
            }
            else if (examScore >= 70 && examScore <=79) {
                gradeC++;
                totalScores++;
            }
            else if (examScore >= 60 && examScore <=69) {
                gradeD++;
                totalScores++;
            }
            else if (examScore >= 0 && examScore <=59)
                gradeF++;
                totalScores++;           
            }
        }while(examScore >=0);
```

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an opening `{` on the last `else if`.

`nextInt()` returns an `int` so what is the point of `if (examScore != (int)examScore) {`?

You can use `Scanner.hasNextInt()` to check if user has inputted an integer. If not, consume the input and try again.

You can simplify the grade conditionals by taking advantage of the fact that in an `if/else if/else`, once one block is executed the rest are skipped.

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter an integer grade percentage: ");
    do {
        // Check for integer
        while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
            // Not an int? Consume and discard
            String input = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Not an integer, please try again.");
        }
        examScore = keyboard.nextInt();
    } while (examScore > 100); // Only except if in range
    if (examScore >= 90) {
        gradeA++;
    }
    else if (examScore >= 80) {
        gradeB++;
    }
    else if (examScore >= 70) {
        gradeC++;
    }
    else if (examScore >= 60) {
        gradeD++;
    }
    else if (examScore >= 0) {
        gradeF++;
    }
    else {
        // Must be negative
        break;
    }
    totalScores++; 
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Just out of curiosity, I had used the checking for integer from another question posted on here. How exactly does the do while loop work? From do down to the close and while (examScore > 100); is what I'm meaning.

Comment: The inner `while` loop loops until user has entered an integer. The outer `do/while` loop loops until the user has entered an integer <= 100. So 101, 102, ... are not accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowed the validation from [Johnny Mopp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66037212/how-do-i-make-this-program-check-if-an-input-is-an-integer-without-causing-an-er/66037369#66037369)

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] scoreLimits = new int[]{90, 80, 70, 60, 0}; // this should be in descending order
        final int[] gradeCount = new int[scoreLimits.length];
        final char[] gradeLabel = new char[]{'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'};
        final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter an integer grade percentage between 0 and 100(both inclusive). Enter -1 to stop");
        while (true) {
            int examScore;
            do {
                // Check for integer
                while (!keyboard.hasNextInt()) {
                    // Not an int? Consume and discard
                    String input = keyboard.next();
                    System.out.println("Not an integer, please try again.");
                }
                examScore = keyboard.nextInt();
            } while (examScore != -1 && (examScore < 0 || examScore > 100)); // Only except if in range

            if (examScore == -1) {
                break;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < scoreLimits.length; i++) {
                if (examScore >= scoreLimits[i]) {
                    ++gradeCount[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(gradeCount));
    }
```

Comment: I should have noted I haven't gone over arrays yet in my class. My apologies!